# How to get exact response from http services

Tags: android, http

In my application, i am working with http services here in my application i have to one edit-text and two buttons(preview button, send button). when i click on preview button, http request will establish with the content of edit-text. and the i want display the response and edit-text content both on a dialogue box.

**This the URL:**
"http://invitations.in/events/register/credit.php?template="+sms_content

**Here is the response:**

{"credits":2}

**And here is my code:**

```
 editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sms_content);

        preview_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.preview_btn);
        send_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_btn);

        send_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        preview_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        preview_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                sms_content = editText.getText().toString();

                // get prompts.xml view
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                 TextView preview = (TextView) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.preview);
                 TextView smscount = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.count_credits);
                 TextView numofcont = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.no_ofcont);

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            try {
                                sms_content = URLEncoder.encode(sms_content, "UTF-8");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://v.leonas.in/events/register/credit.php?template="+sms_content);
                                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                                String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
                                creditspersms = jsonObject.getInt("credits");
                                System.out.println(creditspersms);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.start();

                preview.setText(sms_content);
                smscount.setText(String.valueOf(creditspersms * contnum));
                numofcont.setText(Integer.toString(contnum));

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                        // get user input and set it to result
                                        // edit text
                                        editText.setText(editText.getText());
                                        send_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        preview_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

here when i click on preview button it is hitting the URL and getting response from it. 
But in alert dialogue box the response showing 0. if i cancel the dialogue box and i click again on preview button it is giving exact output what i want.
but i want this on my first click, please help me to solve this.

Comment: Use Async Task instead of the Thread. In post execute of Async Task build the Alert Dialogue

Comment: The problem is alert dialogue is build before the result is recieved by the client. For Asynchronus Works where the response time is unkown use Async Task

Comment: thanks for this replay, is there any example code for this

Comment: Check My Answer. If It helps you Acknowledge me

Comment: If you want to optimize the code, use `Retrofit` or `Volley`. Everything will get handled by these libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like below code :

```
final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    try {
                        sms_content = URLEncoder.encode(sms_content, "UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://v.leonas.in/events/register/credit.php?template=" + sms_content);
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
                        creditspersms = jsonObject.getInt("credits");
                        System.out.println(creditspersms);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        preview.setText(sms_content);
                        smscount.setText(String.valueOf(creditspersms * contnum));
                        numofcont.setText(Integer.toString(contnum));

                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                // get user input and set it to result
                                                // edit text
                                                editText.setText(editText.getText());
                                                send_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                preview_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            }
                                        })
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of **AsyncTask HTTP Request**

```
public class HttpGetRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
   public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
   public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
   public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;
   @Override 
   protected String doInBackground(String... params){
      String stringUrl = params[0];
      String result;
      String inputLine;
      try {
         //Create a URL object holding our url
         URL myUrl = new URL(stringUrl);
         //Create a connection
         HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)     
                myUrl.openConnection();
         //Set methods and timeouts
         connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
         connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
         connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

         //Connect to our url
         connection.connect()
         //Create a new InputStreamReader
         InputStreamReader streamReader = new 
             InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
         //Create a new buffered reader and String Builder
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         //Check if the line we are reading is not null
         while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
         }
         //Close our InputStream and Buffered reader
         reader.close();
         streamReader.close();
         //Set our result equal to our stringBuilder
         result = stringBuilder.toString();
      }
      catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         result = null;
      }
      return result;   
   }
   protected void onPostExecute(String result){
      super.onPostExecute(result);

      // result is your result string. Do your logic here. 
   }
}
```

Hope this may help you.

To know More Read

1. [AsyncTask Android Developeres](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
2. [AsyncTask Example](https://www.journaldev.com/9708/android-asynctask-example-tutorial)